Drupal 10 error after installation of CiviCRM
Summary:
Error in Drupal permissions page (admin/people/permissions/module/civicrm) after fresh install of CiviCRM 5.74.4:

InvalidArgumentException: "0" is an invalid render array key. Value
should be an array but got a string. in
Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of
core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

Details:
I have a fresh installation of Drupal 10.3.0 with PHP 8.2.20 on ddev v1.23.3. Only default core modules are enabled. No custom modules.
I followed all the instructions on  https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/#drupal10-download to "Get the code for Drupal 10".
In WSL2, I did this to add the latest CiviCRM version to D10:
  cd ~proj/websitename
  ddev composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}
  ddev composer require civicrm/cli-tools

This worked perfectly. Two modules were installed, but not yet enabled: civicrm and civicrmtheme.
Next, in order to enable both modules:
  ddev ssh

and then, in directory /var/www/html$,
  cv core:install --cms-base-url=https://websitename.ddev.site/

This works almost perfectly. All CiviCRM functionalities seem to work. All Drupal functionalities work as well, except for one: https://websitename.ddev.site/admin/people/permissions/module/civicrm. This page shows the following error:

InvalidArgumentException: "0" is an invalid render array key. Value
should be an array but got a string. in
Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of
core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
and a lot of lines of code which I can provide if necessary.

The error doesn't show up with any of the other modules. It does also show up however with https://websitename.ddev.site/admin/people/permissions.
Before cv core: install, this error didn't show up.
What I have tried:
line 82 to 98 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php contain the following code:
82 if (is_array($value)) {
     ...
93 }
94 // comment
95 // comment
96 elseif (isset($value)) {
97   throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('"%s" is an invalid render array key. Value should be an array but got a %s.', $key, gettype($value)));
98 }

When line 97 is commented out, the problem disappears. This is obviously not the final solution.
I guess the cause of the problem lies in the code for which is_array($value) is false. I suppose this occurs somewhere in the civicrm code. Unfortunatly I am unable to track it down.
Can someone offer some help or guidance please?

I'm seeing the same error on a D10/Civi site that I've just updated to the same versions: Drupal 10.3 and Civi 5.74.4. The site seems to work, although I get a fatal error at admin/people/permissions. I've spent the last couple of days trying to track this down as a Drupal error without success, so knowing that it is being triggered by CiviCRM is a step forward.

This is fixed in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8/pull/94.
5.74 backport at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8/pull/96

Many thanks. That works for me.

This gets my permissions page back to functional. Many thanks.
